# installing a virtual instance of Windows 2008 on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

The Microsoft documentation says I can run 4 virtual instances of Windows 2008 R2 Server under Hyper-V, with the host system's Windows 2008 R2 Server Enterprise licence.

Is there a special way of installing a such virtual instance, or do I create it in the standard way from the original instal media.

Does anyone know how the licensing works for virtual instances of created in this way - do I input the same product key on the virtual instances and activate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific way to install it for Hyper-V (there's lots of ways to do it, but no one specific).

Form what MS told me, you just install and use the same key.  If you have trouble with activating over the Internet, you can call the activation line and they'll help you out.